# Ifnum operations

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

I had write in my code

```
\newcommand \no {#1} % #1 is a number
\ifnum\i<\no....etc...\else....\fi.
```

But instead of it I need to multiply #1 per 3 and then sum another number.
I tried `\ifnum\i < {2*#2+5}` but it didn't work.
What is the correct syntax? Thx in advance.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} %not working
\foreach \i in {1,...,21}
\fill[\ifnum\i<{3*#2-1}\acommand\else\anothercommand\fi] (90-360/21*\i:.55cm) circle [x radius=1mm, y radius=.5mm, rotate=90-360/21*\i];
\node (0,0) {\LARGE\sffamily\bf \textsf{#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `\numexpr <expression> \relax` to evaluate an integer expression in an `\ifnum` context.  Beware though that `\numexpr` does not really perform integer arithmetic when it comes to division.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\acommand{blue}
\newcommand\anothercommand{red}
\newcommand\WhyWouldAnybodyUseATikzpictureInsideACommand[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,21} {
      \fill[\ifnum\i<\numexpr3*#2-1\relax \acommand\else\anothercommand\fi] (90-360/21*\i:.55cm) circle [x radius=1mm, y radius=.5mm, rotate=90-360/21*\i];
    }
    \node (0,0) {\LARGE\sffamily\bf \textsf{#2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\WhyWouldAnybodyUseATikzpictureInsideACommand{unused}{5}
\end{document}
```

> [image]